# Envíar datos por ajax a un pdf

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf, fpdf

estoy enviando los datos por ajax a un pdf que es creado con la librería fpdf, pero al momento de abrir el pdf lo abre en blanco o solo muestra los datos estaticos y no los que se le envían.
¿Hay algun error al momento de recibirlos? porque en la consola si muestra los datos del input

Formulario

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>  
<body>

<input type="text" name="dato1" id="dato1"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="guardar"  id="guardar" onclick="pdf()">

<script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Este es el código

```js
function pdf(){
                         
  var consulta = $("#dato1").val();
  //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo 
  console.log(consulta);
  //hace la búsqueda
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script/pdf.php",
    data: "dato="+consulta,
    // dataType: "html",
    // xhrFields: {
    //     responseType: 'blob'
    // },
    success: function (data) {
       
        console.log(data);
        //Obtenemos la respuesta para convertirla a blob
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        //Creamos objeto URL
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        //Abrir en una nueva pestaña
        window.open(downloadUrl);
        // window.open("script/pdf.php");
     
    },
    error: function (err) {
      ShowModalCargando(false);
      console.log("Error al intentar realizar el pdf: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  });
    
}
```

Y este es el código del pdf

```html
<?php 
require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
$dato1 = $_POST['dato'];

class pdf extends FPDF
{
  public function header()
  {
  }
  public function footer()
  { 
  }
}

$fpdf = new pdf('P', 'mm', 'letter', true);
$fpdf->AddPage('PORTRAIT', 'letter');
$fpdf->SetMargins(20,10,20,20);

$fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$fpdf->SetXY(20,10);
$fpdf->Cell(0,10,'ESCUELA SECUNDARIA TECNICA ',0,0,'C');
$fpdf->SetXY(20,16);
$fpdf->Cell(0,10,'" NOMBRE "',0,0,'C');
$fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$fpdf->SetXY(20,24);
$fpdf->Cell(0,10,$dato1,0,0,'C');

$fpdf->OutPut('I', 'Citatorio.pdf');

 ?>
```

Si coloco esta línea en el ajax `window.open(downloadUrl);` muestra el documento en blanco
Pero si pongo `window.open("script/pdf.php");` muestra la información estatica pero no los datos que envía

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.open no sirve para eso debe ser enviado por post y window.open no enviá nada por post, lo que debes hacer es enviar por ajax para guardar la información en sesión no en $_POST[] asi si estaran los datos después cuando lo llame por window.open

así podría ser:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Iniciar o reanudar la sesión

require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');

if(isset($_POST['dato'])) {
    $_SESSION['dato'] = $_POST['dato']; // Almacenar el dato en una variable de sesión
}

class pdf extends FPDF {
    public function header() {
    }
    public function footer() { 
    }
}

$fpdf = new pdf('P', 'mm', 'letter', true);
$fpdf->AddPage('PORTRAIT', 'letter');
$fpdf->SetMargins(20,10,20,20);

$fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$fpdf->SetXY(20,10);
$fpdf->Cell(0,10,'ESCUELA SECUNDARIA TECNICA ',0,0,'C');
$fpdf->SetXY(20,16);
$fpdf->Cell(0,10,'" NOMBRE "',0,0,'C');
$fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);

// Obtener el dato almacenado en la variable de sesión
$dato1 = isset($_SESSION['dato']) ? $_SESSION['dato'] : '';

$fpdf->SetXY(20,24);
$fpdf->Cell(0,10,$dato1,0,0,'C');

$fpdf->OutPut('I', 'Citatorio.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!!!